# Grails - Apache Commons Collection vulnerability

Tags: hibernate, security, grails, apache-commons-collection

Regarding the following vulnerability found in the commons-collections library,

https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/576313

I’ve found that the affected version 3.2.1 is pulled into hibernate (3.6.10.18) in the Grails project I am running under 2.5.5.
Does this use of the library pose any threat in terms of exposing the vulnerability. 
Should I be importing the patched version (3.2.2) as a direct dependency to mitigate any chance of exposure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vulnerable class in question (`InvokerTransformer`) has never been used in the Grails codebase, and I don't see a circumstance where this vulnerability is exploitable in a Grails application.

Nevertheless you can of course upgrade to 3.2.2 just be specifying the dependency in your `BuildConfig.groovy` or `build.gradle` file

Comment: Thanks @Graeme, seems like I can be comfortable with this dependency without having to patch. I prefer not the override dependencies where possible regardless of how insignificant it may appear to be.